# Python Sequential number generator with no repeats

Tags: python, random

I'm trying to create a number generator in a sort of unconventional way. I'm completely new to python. I came up with 2 approaches and I'm getting sort of the results that I want, but it's incomplete and I don't know where to go next.

Approach 1

```
col1 = [1,2,3,4,5,7,8,10,13,16] 
col2 = [2,4,5,6,7,9,11,13,14,15,17,18,19,20,21,22] 
col3 = [7,8,10,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,23,24,25,27,29,30] 
col4 = [9,12,17,18,19,20,22,23,24,25,26,28,30,31,33] 
col5 = [20,21,24,25,26,28,30,32,33,34,35] 
b1 = [1,3,5,7,8] 
b2 = [2,4,6,7,9,10,11,12] 
drum1 = random.sample(col1 + col2 + col3 + col4 + col5, k=5) 
drum2 = random.sample(b1 + b2, k=2) 
draw1 = random.sample(drum1, k=5) 
draw2 = random.sample(drum2, k=2) 
main_draw = draw1 + draw2 main_draw

[30, 13, 28, 5, 30, 2, 4]
```

Approach 2

```
for num in range(4): 
first = random.choice(col1) 
second = random.choice(col2) 
third = random.choice(col3) 
forth = random.choice(col4) 
fifth = random.choice(col5) 
bonus1 = random.choice(b1) 
bonus2 = random.choice(b2) 
draw = f'{first} {second} {third} {forth} {fifth} {bonus1} {bonus2}' print(draw)

7 6 7 23 21 5 2 
13 11 14 20 30 8 9 
4 6 23 17 20 5 11 
5 22 23 23 20 7 11
```

In one approach I used the .choice and the other approach the .sample.

1. My first goal is to get unique random numbers from the range of numbers I manually enter and not from say, random(1,30). I would like to give it the numbers I want it to rand between. But I want each number to be unique and as you can see from the results, that's not the case.
2. My second goal is to develop this further so that from the numbers I provide in each column as you noticed, some of the numbers in different columns are the same, I want it that way, however, I would also like it to count up, so if it chose 7 from col1 then it should start from a number greater than 7 in col2 and if it is, say 10, then it should choose one of the numbers in col3 that is greater than 10 and so on until col5.

Can you please help me?
Thank you

Comment: You didn't give us `col1`.

Comment: It's there. The formatting was just broken.

Comment: Why not just use random.randint? Use an if/else to avoid repeats.

Answer (score 0):

This does what you want.  You're restricting the set of numbers for the later picks rather severely.

```
import random

col1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10,13,16]
col2 = [2,4,5,6,7,9,11,13,14,15,17,18,19,20,21,22] 
col3 = [7,8,10,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,23,24,25,27,29,30] 
col4 = [9,12,17,18,19,20,22,23,24,25,26,28,30,31,33] 
col5 = [20,21,24,25,26,28,30,32,33,34,35] 
b1 = [1,3,5,7,8] 
b2 = [2,4,6,7,9,10,11,12] 

def pickem():
    pick1 = random.choice(col1)
    pick2 = random.choice( [i for i in col2 if i > pick1] )
    pick3 = random.choice( [i for i in col3 if i > pick2] )
    pick4 = random.choice( [i for i in col4 if i > pick3] )
    pick5 = random.choice( [i for i in col5 if i > pick4] )

    bonus1 = random.choice(b1)
    bonus2 = random.choice(b2)

    return (pick1,pick2,pick3,pick4,pick5,bonus1,bonus2)

print( pickem() )
print( pickem() )
print( pickem() )
print( pickem() )
print( pickem() )
print( pickem() )
```

Comment: Doesn't this oversample larger numbers? It requires that each set of  possibilities includes at least one value greater than any value in the previous set --maybe that's true since the problem is underspecified-- which leads me to suspect that the final selection will be biased towards collections which include these values. Maybe I'm wrong; I didn't test it.

Comment: "You're restricting the set of numbers for the later picks rather severely." What do you mean?

Comment: Yes, it absolutely does, but that's what he wanted.

Comment: For example, if you pick 30 for `col3`, there are only two possible choices for `col4` and only two or three for `col5`.  That's not very random.

Comment: Oh, I get you. Yes, you're right. it does and it's not completely random. It's just something I'm trying out. These numbers are numbers that appear most frequently, so I wanted to try picking the next number that is higher than the previous out of those frequent numbers to see what that looks like. It was something I was trying in excel but couldn't figure out how to do it so I tried python. I'm probably not making much sense.

Comment: However, the above code is doing what I wanted, so thank you so much. Is there a way to weight the numbers because some of them are more frequent than others so it can take these odds into consideration like in the random.choices function?

Comment: You do understand that lotteries are PHYSICALLY random, not just pseudo-random, right?  They cannot be predicted.  There are no trends.  If there were, they'd go out of business.  What you're doing is pointless.

Comment: Yes I know, lol, but thank you for your help anyway, I'm really grateful. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a while clause:

```
final_list = []
print('Enter Number 1')   # Ask for num 1
number1 = input()
print('Enter Number 2')   # Ask for num 2
number2 = input()
while len(final_list) < 10:    # Continue running loop until your list has 10 digits, adjust to whatever you want 
    new_number = random.choice(range(number1, number2)   # Generate a new number
    if new_number in final_list:   # Check if already in list
        pass
    elif new_number <= final_list[-1]:    # Check if new num is greater most recent addition
        pass
    else:
        final_list.append(new_number)
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the requirements.  He wants to pick the numbers from his lists.

Comment: He says his first goal is to get random numbers from a range he enters, but yeah I'm not sure how that fits in with all the columns he entered

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I'm completely new to python. Started just a week ago and I'm also not a coder so I'm sure the way I did this is the least effective way. lol So any help, with as much explanation as you can please, would be greatly appreciated.